# I am trying to install ffmpeg in mac

Tags: macos, installation, ffmpeg

I am trying to install ffmpeg in mac with this command `brew install ffmpeg` but in my 4 attepmts i got this message for about 2 hours

```
==> Installing ffmpeg dependency: rust
Warning: A newer Command Line Tools release is available.
Update them from Software Update in System Preferences or run:
  softwareupdate --all --install --force

If that doesn't show you any updates, run:
  sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
  sudo xcode-select --install

Alternatively, manually download them from:
  https://developer.apple.com/download/all/.
You should download the Command Line Tools for Xcode 11.3.1.

==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/rust/1.56.1 --release-channel=stable
==> make
```

the installation it was stopped 4 times, i am tired what is happening?

Comment: xcode 11.3 is fairly obsolete- it was released on Mojave, which is no longer supported by brew.   We would need to know your macOS version.  looks like you are on an *intel* mac judging by the `/usr/local` in the path.  ffmpeg is built using a particular toolchain in your example, which shows it is not installing from the bottle, but rather attempting to configure a source build.  Usually there is no disadvantage- unless your OS is no longer supported by `brew`.  Best way to install ffmpeg is using a build from https://evermeet.cx/ffmpeg/

Comment: @RichardBarber my version mojave 10.14.6

Comment: @RichardBarber how can i install in my old mac?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xcode 11.3 is fairly obsolete- it was released on Mojave, which is no longer supported by brew. We would need to know your macOS version. looks like you are on an intel mac judging by the /usr/local in the path. ffmpeg is built using a particular toolchain in your example, which shows it is not installing from the bottle, but rather attempting to configure a source build. Usually there is no disadvantage- unless your OS is no longer supported by brew.

- Best way to install ffmpeg on Mojave?
  Use a prebuilt binary from the link provided by ffmpeg.org: https://evermeet.cx/ffmpeg